# How to create a Certificate Sign Request (PKCS10) in Qt Creator (C++)?

Tags: c++, qt, x509, csr

I want to create a **Certificate Sign Request (CSR)** which takes **common name, organization, email id** etc details in **PKCS10** format using **C++** in `Qt Creator`.

I have tried using `QtCrypto` [QCA](http://delta.affinix.com/docs/qca/)
but unable to create it.